# "[ODBC Microsoft Access Driver] Not a valid file name"

Tags: python, ms-access, odbc, pyodbc

I am new to Python and Pyodbc. I try to connect an access database with below code but keep getting "[ODBC Microsoft Access Driver] Not a valid file name" error.

I tried to install Access Database Engine and using two backslashes instead of one in the database directory.

When I look at the ODBC data sources Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb) seems to be installed. I tried It on another system with no luck.

```
import pyodbc

conn_str = (
    r'DRIVER={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};'
    r'DBQ="C:\Users\PC\Desktop\testdatabase.accdb";'
    )
cnxn = pyodbc.connect(conn_str)
crsr = cnxn.cursor()
for physical_properties in crsr.tables(tableType='TABLE'):
    print(physical_properties.table_name)
```

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Does https://github.com/mkleehammer/pyodbc/issues/922 help? It was the second result (after this question) when I tried copying and pasting `"[ODBC Microsoft Access Driver] Not a valid file name"` (with quotes) [into a search engine](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=%22%5BODBC+Microsoft+Access+Driver%5D+Not+a+valid+file+name%22). Please try to [research](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/) questions before asking. (Fittingly enough, the problem is caused by quotation marks.)

Answer (score 1):

The filespec cannot have quotes around it. This fails

```py
    connection_string = (
        r'DRIVER={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};'
        r'DBQ="C:\Users\Public\Database1.accdb";'
    )
```

but this works

```py
    connection_string = (
        r'DRIVER={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};'
        r'DBQ=C:\Users\Public\Database1.accdb;'
    )
```

Comment: Thank you very much, it worked when quotation were removed. Apparently it was a simple error but I was lost. Have a great day.